# Integration with a swipe card check-in system?

Tags: civimember

Our charity currently operates a manual check in system for users of our facilities. We are considering installing a swipe-card automated system at the gate. Can this be integrated with Civi CRM so we know who has checked in when. No payment is taken at check in.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same but for a similar way of automating check-in take a look at https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin